# Does anyone know the details of the 'great festival of Dogs' (Kukur-Mahotsava)?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism

[image]Sri Radharaman Charan Das Babaji was a great Gaudiya Vaishnava saint, who had a pet-dog named 'Bhakti-Maa'.

At the sraddha of Bhakti-Maa, hundreds of street dogs were invited and they all attended and took meal in a very disciplined way.

Can someone provide the details of this astonishing event? Thanks.